# rails model callback not running during model spec

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rspec, model, ruby-on-rails-5

I have a Link model with several validations. When I run the entire rspec suite, the spec fails on the last validation "should not allow an invalid url"

However, when I run `rspec spec/models/link_spec.rb`, the model spec passes. The `validate_url` method is never called. My rails app is also ignoring the callback upon model creation.

Here is my model:

```
require 'uri'

class Link < ApplicationRecord
  belongs_to :user

  validates :url, presence: true
  validates :title, presence: true
  validates :read, absence: false
  validates :user_id, presence: true

  before_save :validate_url

  private

  def validate_url
    require 'pry'; binding.pry
    uri = URI.parse(self.url)
    uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
  rescue URI::InvalidURIError
    false
  end
end
```

and my model spec:

```
require 'rails_helper'

describe Link, type: :model do
  it { should validate_presence_of :url }
  it { should validate_presence_of :title }
  it { should validate_presence_of :user_id }

  it "should not allow an invalid url" do
    link = Link.create({
      title: "new link",
      url: "garbage",
      user_id: 1
    })

    expect(link.valid?).to be_falsey
    expect(link.save).to be_falsey
  end
end
```

Any ideas why the callback method is not accessed? I'm on Rails 5.0.0.1 and RSpec 3.5.4

Answer (score 1):

`before_*` methods are mostly used to prepare data, or to do something else before an action happens. Validations need to happen in the `validation` step of and ActiveRecord object. So, I would remove that code and place it in a `validate` sentence.

You can either use something like:

```
validate :url_format
...
private
def url_format
  uri = URI.parse(self.url)
  uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
rescue URI::InvalidURIError
  errors.add(:url, 'Url is invalid')
end
```

or you can also use the `validate` `format` helper:

```
validate :url, format: { with: URI::regexp(%w(http https)) }
```

I don't know why your solution works when you run your spec file. I read the documentation, and it states that by returning `:abort` in any `before_*` callback will abort the `save` action and will return false.

UPDATE: returning `false` doesn't prevent the record from being saved, you need to add the error to the errors collection:

```
private
def url_format
  uri = URI.parse(self.url)
  errors.add(:url, 'Url is invalid') unless uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP)
end
```

Comment: Thank you for the tips... but still running into the same problem even with url_format in a validate sentence. The method is being called and the line uri.kind_of?(URI::HTTP) returns false. The method itself returns false when called from the Rails console. But, the validate sentence does not prevent the db save transaction from occurring

Comment: Sorry, I think I did't read well the code you had. Let me update the answer a little bit, I'll remove the rescue you have.